# Is there a way to compute the derivative of points using R

Tags: r, mean, derivative

I have a bunch of data points that depict the frequency (no unit) at different times (seconds). I have several of these for different parts of a cell. I need to be able to compute the derivatives of each point in each column for all the data using R. Is this possible? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Please let me know if I am not being specific enough.

Thanks

Comment: A first attempt would use `diff(x) / diff(time)`, though that's length 1 shorter than the original data, and it is biased either left or right, not "centered" as gradients often are.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081069/calculate-the-derivative-of-a-data-function-in-r) has some useful answers.